# Gradle doesn't see Kotlin dependency from mavenLocal

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, multiplatform

I'm trying to extract a part of my Kotlin Gradle project to a separate repository. It's a Kotlin multiplatform project (https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth) and I want to extract [whatever sits in 'plotassert' package](https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/tree/master/core/src/main/kotlin/it/krzeminski/testutils/plotassert).

I followed https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/multiplatform-library.html. To test it locally, I published the newly extracted project to the local Maven repository by executing `publishToMavenLocal` Gradle's task, and then put `mavenLocal()` in the main project's `repositories` section ([here](https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/blob/master/build.gradle#L14), as the first item). In `core` project's dependencies ([here](https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/blob/master/core/build.gradle#L4)) I put

```
compile "it.krzeminski.plotassert:PlotAssert:0.0.1"
```

The problem is that IntelliJ/Gradle don't see this dependency, also when trying to use some class from the code:

[image: not visible]

If I deliberately use some wrong dependency name, Gradle notices it:

[image: wrong name]

so it means that it somehow sees that the dependency exists in the local repo. I also see in `~/.m2/repository` that the local publication produced some files:

```
:~/.m2/repository$ tree
.
└── it
    └── krzeminski
        └── plotassert
            ├── PlotAssert
            │   ├── 0.0.1
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-0.0.1.module
            │   │   └── PlotAssert-0.0.1.pom
            │   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
            ├── PlotAssert-js
            │   ├── 0.0.1
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-js-0.0.1.jar
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-js-0.0.1.module
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-js-0.0.1.pom
            │   │   └── PlotAssert-js-0.0.1-sources.jar
            │   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
            ├── PlotAssert-jvm
            │   ├── 0.0.1
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-jvm-0.0.1.jar
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-jvm-0.0.1.module
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-jvm-0.0.1.pom
            │   │   └── PlotAssert-jvm-0.0.1-sources.jar
            │   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
            ├── PlotAssert-linux
            │   ├── 0.0.1
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-linux-0.0.1.klib
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-linux-0.0.1.module
            │   │   ├── PlotAssert-linux-0.0.1.pom
            │   │   └── PlotAssert-linux-0.0.1-sources.jar
            │   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
            └── PlotAssert-metadata
                ├── 0.0.1
                │   ├── PlotAssert-metadata-0.0.1.jar
                │   ├── PlotAssert-metadata-0.0.1.module
                │   ├── PlotAssert-metadata-0.0.1.pom
                │   └── PlotAssert-metadata-0.0.1-sources.jar
                └── maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Isn't this behavior of Gradle or IntelliJ incorrect? My understanding is that it should list this dependency under "Source Sets", like it did in case of the incorrect name.

I haven't tried yet to publish the newly extracted project to some online repo because I'd like to have a chance to iterate locally instead of publishing each change.

Could you give me a pointer what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had

```
enableFeaturePreview('GRADLE_METADATA')
```

in the library project, but didn't have it in the consumer project. Adding it and bumping Gradle wrapper version to 4.9 solved the issue.